# проблемы с файлами .rtf в проекте C# Привязка к свойству или столбцу ... для DataSource невозможна

Tags: c#

В проекте использую файлы .rtf.

Обращаюсь к ним так: contentTxt.LoadFile("../Static.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText); - загрузка содержимого rtf в richtextbox.

При сборке проекта и запуске ехе-шника на другом компе выдает ошибку: Привязка к свойству или столбцу ... для DataSource невозможна.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: contentTxt.LoadFile("Files/MyFile"). Но нужно будет таскать папку Files с нужными файлами рядом с .exe`шником. Если нужно одним файлом, то можно SFX архив собрать.

Answer (score 0):

в richtextbox в Data Bindings-Advanced была какая-то информация, после удаления которой ошибка исчезла.

Так и не разобралась, зачем нужна привязка данных (в данном случае). Из теории понимаю, что привязка нужна для автоматического обновления данных.